# Hide discussion comment using GitHub graphQL api

Tags: graphql, github-api, github-graphql

In a github discussion I am pinging folks who have pending PRs to review and to make the discussion less noisy I want to hide all previous comments before posting new comments. Probably this `hide` option would be good but I am not getting how to do it using the graphql api or even it is possible to do it with the api in current scenario. Also, any other suggestion to keep the discussion less noisy would be very helpful. Thanks you!

I tried looking into [this](https://docs.github.com/en/graphql/reference/mutations) documentation but I didn't find something useful.[image]